# Flask session not persisting

Tags: python, ajax, session, flask

I have a web application running on a Flask backend with a JS client handling the front-end work. I'm running into problems trying to save a key-value pair to Flask's session object (`flask.session`) through a simple Flask API.

The session object I'm trying to modify is called `account_id` and the two API routes basically look like this:

**GET**

```
@access_service.route('/current_account.json', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def show_current_account():
    return jsonify(account_id=session.get('account_id'))
```

**POST**

```
@access_service.route('/current_account.json', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def update_current_account():
if request.json:
    session['account_id'] = request.json['account_id']
    return jsonify(account_id=session.get('account_id'))
return jsonify()
```

In the JS frontend a call to the POST route is made as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/current_account.json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({ 'account_id': 10 })
});
```

Which does appear to work correctly, the ajax call returns with 200 OK and a correct return value. Logging from the Flask application also reveals that the session now contains the key `account_id` with value 10. However, looking up `/current_account.json` immediately after the POST request is made simply returns an `account_id` with value `null`.

What's stranger still is that using a simple in-browser REST client and making an identical POST request to `current_account.json` causes the session to work and persist as expected through full-page refresh, etc. Since that is the case, it leads me to believe that the problem has to do with the request itself rather than with Flask's session object, although I can't seem to figure out what exactly is causing it.

Comment: There are some options you can use for your session that might help debug a little more. You might try using `session.modified` right after updating the session. Though flask should track the change your making, telling the session that it has changed explicitly might propagate your change. If it does, then that might give us a better idea about what's happening. Additionally, you might try setting `session.permanent_session_lifetime` equal to `True`. This will ensure that a session lives across browser closings. This might help us diagnose if it's a header/javascript/request issue.

Comment: I added logging for `session.modified` after changing the session in the POST route, which outputs `True`. For your second point, I assume you're referring to `session.permanent` which led me to a discovery.  
  
Logging out `session.permanent` in POST/GET routes returned `False` in both cases, using `$.ajax` and the REST client.  
  
Setting `session.permanent = True` in the POST route, it had reverted to `False` in the GET route using `$.ajax`, but remained `True` using the REST client.  
  
The end result was the same though, using the REST client persists the session but $.ajax doesn't.

Comment: Not sure if this could help but you might want to look at the ajax calls documentation for flask. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/

Comment: can you check whether the ajax request carries the same session cookie as e.g. your REST client call?

Comment: The "Cookie" header is identical in both cases. I've even tried setting custom headers in the `$.ajax` request to match the REST client request exactly but still no luck.

Comment: However, that got us thinking that it might be a browser issue in that cookies from an XHR are discarded but not in the case of the REST client's request. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method), for example. We're a little stumped by this so please correct me if any of this is wrong. In any case, we will be using redis as a session store so we'll be able to bypass the problem that way.

Answer (score 3):

In my previous project, we experienced the same issue and it turns out that $.ajax does not carry cookies. We used manual session store to remedy the problem.