# Sessions always empty with flask / heroku

Tags: python, session, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm having an issue with my application on Heroku where sessions aren't persisting. Specifically, flask's SecureCookieSession object is empty, every time a request is made. Contrast this with running my application on localhost, where the contents of SecureCookieSession persist the way they should.

Also I'm using flask-login + flask-seasurf, but I'm pretty sure the issue happening somewhere between flask / gunicorn / heroku.

Here are three questions that describe a similar issue:

1. [Flask sessions not persisting on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631908/flask-sessions-not-persisting-on-heroku)
2. [Flask session not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915989/flask-session-not-persisting)
3. [Flask-Login and Heroku issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614877/flask-login-and-heroku-issues)

Except I'm not dealing with AJAX or multiple workers here (it's a single heroku free dyno, with a single line in the Procfile). I do get the feeling that using [server side sessions with redis](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/) or switching from Heroku to something like EC2 might solve my problem though.

Also, here's my git repo if it helps https://gitlab.com/collectqt/quirell/tree/develop. And I'm testing session stuff with

```
def _before_request(self):
    LOG.debug('SESSION REQUEST '+str(flask.session))

def _after_request(self, response):
    LOG.debug('SESSION RESPONSE '+str(flask.session))
    return response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the solved with some external help, mainly by changing the secret key to use a random string I came up with, instead of os.urandom(24)

Changing to server side redis sessions helped too, if only by making testing simpler

Comment: What was the secret key before you replaced with `os.urandom(24)` ? IIRC flask has SecureCookie backend.

Comment: I changed **from**  `os.urandom(24)` **to** a random string that I typed, sort similar to `AAAAAAAaaaaaa!!!!!!`.

(although obviously the secret key in production looks nothing like that)

I have a feeling that what os.urandom(24) was generating was breaking heroku's version of hmac

Also yes, flask uses SecureCookie

Comment: I did the same mistake before. If you put `SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)` in `settings.py` or something. The key will change every time (hopefuly ;) the (dev?) server restarts and it will make the cookie invalid because the token (secure hash of cookie's key/value pairs) can not be validated with the new secret key. In this case, flask reset the cookie, so it appears empty. http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/11/17/my-favorite-database/ might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else comes across this question, check `APPLICATION_ROOT` configuration variable. I recently deployed a Flask application to a subdirectory under nginx with a reverse-proxy and setting the `APPLICATION_ROOT` variable broke Flask's session. Cookies aren't being set under the correct path because of that.